# The service "security.command.debug_firewall" has a dependency on a non-existent service

Tags: symfony5.4

I'm using Symfony 5.4.10 for my e-commerce site. while generating the authentification form, after entering php bin/console make:auth all necessary files have been generated. But after that, i have this error while executing the login form : The service "security.command.debug_firewall" has a dependency on a non-existent service "App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator"

My Security.yaml file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write
**custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator**

You need to implement this class yourself.

1. Create src/Security folder,
2. create class LoginFormAuthenticator.php
3. extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator.

After that, it will only be necessary to overwrite the methods according to your needs.

Comment: Please include documentation or any other detailed reference to follow. Also explain what `custom_authenticator` is assuming that the OP is not aware of it. And how to avoid it if they didn't intend to create a Custom Authenticator in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I write an answer:

I had the same problem and already did what was written by Aleksey Mikhailov

> If you write
> custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
>
> You need to implement this class yourself.
>
> Create src/Security folder,
> create class LoginFormAuthenticator.php
> extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator.
> After that, it will only be necessary to overwrite the methods according to your needs.

But I also needed to edit the services.yaml by adding this:

```yaml
services:
    # ...
    App\Security\:
        resource: '../src/Security/*'
```